# Is there any way that I can custom the score of any utterances in LUIS?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

In my LUIS account, I have an intent "Login" and an utterance "Vao di" with the initial score about 0.3. After I click to train, I see it updated the score with 0.9.
Is there any way that I can custom / modify the score after clicking training in LUIS webpage / API support? Ex: I want the utterance "Vao di" has value only 0.5 for the first training, then it becomes 0.7 for 2nd time and the 3rd time it will be 0.9.
Please help me to do it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the purpose of this type of custom score per training?

Comment: @DFBerry I have multiple authors to manage one account LUIS. So I would like only one of them to teach like Super Admin role and increase it immediately to 0.9 in the first train. Other roles must have to train it 3 times to get the score to 0.9. Can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Alex, as Ali mentioned, you cannot modify the score manually. The score is the result of under-the-hood LUIS calculations that occur to try to determine the meaning of the user's utterance and in turn the score calculated is how confident LUIS is that the meaning is that particular entity/intent.

You can influence the accuracy of how well LUIS can determine the meaning of a user's utterance by--meaning add more weight to a specific feature--by the following ways:

- Adding more example utterances
- [Using patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-pattern)
- [Using a phrase list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-interchangeable-phrase-list)

Answer (score 2):

You can't increase the score without training, the score is essentially there to tell how trained and efficient it is.

Comment: Thanks Ali. Yes I know. But is there any way that we can increase the score after training and modify / custom it ? Because it will be always over 0.9.